# Are typescript 3.0 type definitions backwards compatible to ts2?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a react component library in typescript 3. How can I ensure that my generated .d.ts files are compatible with typescript 2 codebases?

Comment: Don't use typescript 3.0 or above features. The features are described here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap. If you don't use them it should be compatible, baring you hitting any of the breaking changes ..

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Isn't that an answer?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure, it's rather small .. I geuss it could be :)

Comment: The best way to ensure compatibility with TypeScript 2 would be to test on TypeScript 2, as much work as it is.  There is precedent [in the dtslint tool used by DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/src/rules/expectRule.ts).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use any of the Typescript new features the definitions should be compatible as existing language features have not changed much. The new features are described [here](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap)

There are a number of breaking changes that could affect this, as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes).

This also depends on the specific sub version of 2.x you are targeting. Some new features may be too ubiquitous to avoid in newer versions (conditional types come to mind which were introduced in 2.8)